# audio stream sampling rate in linux

Tags: linux, audio-recording, sampling

Im trying read and store samples from an audio microphone in linux using C/C++. Using PCM ioctls i setup the device to have a certain sampling rate say 10Khz using the SOUND_PCM_WRITE_RATE ioctl etc. The device gets setup correctly and im able to read back from the device after setup using the "read".

```
int got = read(itsFd, b.getDataPtr(), b.sizeBytes());
```

The problem i have is that after setting the appropriate sampling rate i have a thread that continuously reads from /dev/dsp1 and stores these samples, but the number of samples that i get for 1 second of recording are way off the sampling rate and always orders of magnitude more than the set sampling rate. Any ideas where to begin on figuring out what might be the problem?

EDIT:

Partial source code:

```
/////////main loop
while(goforever) {

    // grab a buffer:
    AudioBuffer<uint16> buffer;
    agb->grab(buffer);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&qmutex_data);
    rec.push(buffer);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&qmutex_data);
    if(tim.getSecs()>=5)
      goforever =false;
}

////////////grab function:

template <class T>
void AudioGrabber::grab(AudioBuffer<T>& buf) const
{

  AudioBuffer<T> b(itsBufsamples.getVal(),
                   itsStereo.getVal() ? 2U : 1U,
                   float(itsFreq.getVal()),
                   NO_INIT);
  int got = read(itsFd, b.getDataPtr(), b.sizeBytes());

  if (got != int(b.sizeBytes()))
    PLERROR("Error reading from device: got %d of %u requested bytes",
            got, b.sizeBytes());

  buf = b;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just because you ask for a 10kHz sampling rate, it doesn't mean that your hardware supports it. Many sound cards only support one or two sampling rates - mine for example only supports these:

```
$ grep -rH rates /proc/asound/ | cut -d : -f 2- | sort -u
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    rates [0x5e0]: 44100 48000 88200 96000 192000
```

Therefore, you have to *check* the return value of the `SOUND_PCM_WRITE_RATE` `ioctl()` to verify that you got the rate that you wanted, as mentioned [here](http://www.oreilly.de/catalog/multilinux/excerpt/ch14-05.htm):

> SOUND_PCM_WRITE_RATE
>
> Sets the sampling rate in samples per second. Remember that all sound
>   cards have a limit on the range; the
>   driver will round the rate to the
>   nearest speed supported by the
>   hardware, returning the actual
>   (rounded) rate in the argument.

Comment: I have checked that and the sound card is compatible with the rates im setting, further by doing a SOUND_PCM_READ_RATE ioctl i can read back the rate i set and it works fine. After further testing i have found that some how i get repetition of blocks being read from /dev/dsp1 as if once i read the data it doesn't come off the buffer I dont know why that would be the case?

Comment: yup single channel mono using SOUND_PCM_WRITE_CHANNELS ioctl

Comment: Should I assume that you checked _that_ return value as well, and that the bits/sample are also set and checked?

Comment: Yes it all seems set up correctly and not returning negative values. SOUND_PCM_READ_CHANNELS, SOUND_PCM_READ_BITS, SOUND_PCM_READ_RATE, SNDCTL_DSP_GETBLKSIZE all these are returning the correct values.

Comment: @farhan: You could try using `strace` on e.g. sox as it records from the soundcard. You could also try posting you actual code - you might have a bug somewhere.

Comment: The code is a bit long but I can include the important parts you can see them here: http://pastie.org/1516691

Comment: I should also add that im trying to record from a USB mic