# WAV files at any rate except 44.1kHz have messed up sound

Tags: c++, linux, audio, wav, alsa

I'm using ALSA on Ubuntu to try to play a WAV file. Presently, I'm able to read the wav header to figure out the file's sampling rate and such then set the parameters on ALSA to correspond. This works perfectly for files with a 44.1kHz sampling rate, but other files with rates at ~11kHz or ~22kHz do not play correctly. I'm not sure that I am setting the sampling rate correctly.

```
val = realSampleRate;
    //Sampling rate to given sampling rate
    snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_max(handle, params, &val, &dir);
    cout << "sampling at " << val << " Hz \n";
```

This gives the correct output ("sampling at 22050 Hz") but if I follow it with this:

```
val = realSampleRate;
snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_min(handle, params, &val, &dir);
cout << "sampling at " << val << " Hz \n";
```

the output proceeds to say "sampling at 44100 Hz" which is obviously contradictory. I also tried using `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near` but that doesn't work either, it says sampling at 44100 Hz on a 22050 file, and the audio throughout all of those were very messed up.

EDIT: One issue is incorrect sampling rates, which will speed up the playing, but the real issue comes from mono tracks. Mono tracks sound really distorted and very off.

EDIT: 8 Bit files are off too

Comment: I think the dir parameter is wrong, it seems you are passing an address to an int. This parameter should be -1 for allowing smaller rates, 0 for an exact match and 1 for allowing higher rates. You probably want snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate(handle, params, &val, 0); And also check the return value to look for success.

Comment: Everything is a *lot* easier if you use have PulseAudio installed ... it can take care of a lot of the hard stuff, get rid of the "one application at a time" limit, etc.

Comment: The issue is with setting the amount of channels and the format. It won't let me set it as mono or set the format as 8bit. Any ideas why because I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like your hardware is not capable of handling a 22.05Khz sampling rate for playback. The fact that the API function returns a different value is a clue.

ALSA is just an API. It can only do what your current underlying hardware is capable of supporting. Low-end, bottom-of-the-barrel, el-cheapo audio playback hardware will support a handful of sampling frequencies, and that's about it.

I had some custom-written audio recording and playback software, that was sampling and recording audio at a particular rate, then playing it back using ALSA's `aplay`. When I got some new hardware, I found that the new hardware was still capable of supporting my sampling rate for recording, for playback it didn't, and `aplay` simply proceeded to play back the previously recorded audio at the nearest supportable playback level, with hillarious results. I had to change my custom-written stuff to record and playback at the supported rate.

If the hardware does not support your requested playback rate, ALSA won't resample your raw audio data. It's up to you to resample it, for playback.

Comment: The strange thing is that I can play it perfectly using `aplay` but not programmatically, so that's not the problem.

Comment: It's possible that the current version of aplay will re-sample the raw audio in order to adapt to the correct frequency, although it didn't when I was looking at it. You might want to grab the source to aplay, and see what it does.

Comment: I'm assuming that it doesn't resample it because it says that its playing it at the correct sample rate when I execute it, but I'll see if that's what's going on.

Comment: This appears to be the correct answer. using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848427/audio-stream-sampling-rate-in-linux) it seems only a few sampling rates including and above 44.1kHz are supported.

Comment: The sampling rate actually is not the only problem. It only plays fast because of the sampling rate, but the real problem is stereo vs mono. Mono tracks sound completely distorted, but the same file as stereo is fine (albeit fast if the sampling rate is incorrect). Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

`snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_max()` sets the **maximum** sample rate, i.e., when this functions succeeds, the device's sample rate will not be larger than what you've specified.

`snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_min()` sets the minimum sample rate.

`snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near()` searches for the nearest sample rate that is actually supported by the device, sets it, and returns it.

If you have audio data with a specific sample rate, and cannot do resampling, you must use `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate()`.

Answer (score 0):

Using "default" instead of "hw:0,0" solves this, including the sampling rate being too slow. "plughw:0,0" works as well, and it's better because you can select the different devices/cards programmatically whereas default just uses the default.